# Using javascript to include sum of field values within group of objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have an object full of `tasks` that are grouped by day. I would like to also add up the `time` field of each task to get a total time for each day, and include that in the object.

To go from this:

```
{'Monday': [
  {
    task: 'Do the dishes',
    time: 15
  },
  {
    task: 'Walk the dog',
    time: 20
  }
],
'Tuesday': [
  {
    task: 'Clean house',
    time: 5
  },
  {
    task: 'Do homework',
    time: 10
  }
  ]
}
```

To this:

```
{'Monday': {
  tasks: [
    {
      task: 'Do the dishes',
      time: 15
    },
    {
      task: 'Walk the dog',
      time: 20
    }
  ],
  totalTime: 35
},
'Tuesday': {
  tasks: [
    {
      task: 'Clean house',
      time: 5
    },
    {
      task: 'Do homework',
      time: 10
    }
  ],
  totalTime: 15
}
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lodash's `_.mapValues()` to iterate the groups, and `_.sumBy()` to get the total time:

```js
const obj = { 'Monday': [{ task: 'Do the dishes', time: 15 }, { task: 'Walk the dog', time: 20 } ], 'Tuesday': [{ task: 'Clean house', time: 5 }, { task: 'Do homework', time: 10 } ] }

const result = _.mapValues(obj, tasks => ({
  tasks,
  totalTime: _.sumBy(tasks, 'time')
}))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Choosing this for simplicity with lodash. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this without lodash with just plain JS (ES6 if you want the arrow functions). It is pretty much just [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
const obj = { 'Monday': [{ task: 'Do the dishes', time: 15 }, { task: 'Walk the dog', time: 20 } ], 'Tuesday': [{ task: 'Clean house', time: 5 }, { task: 'Do homework', time: 10 } ] }

const result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((r,[k,v]) => {
  r[k] = ({tasks: v, totalTime: v.reduce((a,b) => (a.time || a) + b.time)})
  return r
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: @MarkMeyer Thanks. Fixed it yesterday but forgot to update :).